# How to get Custom Gird child item click event?

Tags: android, gridview, event-handling

I am struggling with **custom Gird view.** Not exactly with Custom Gird view but its **click event of child view.**

Major two query :

**first :**

issues is if i add simple image view and text view in grid and click on any of the item its working and shows me position of that item.but button when i add two button in grid replacing text view that will not call simple click event of item.

**second :**

i want to get click event for all three view like image and two button.
if i click on image it should be do some task and same as for two button.

see i have this code .

**main java :**

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.mkyong.android.adapter.ImageAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

    GridView gridView;

    private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        prepareList();
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, listCountry, listFlag));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                ImageView img = (ImageView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item" + img.getTag(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }

    public void prepareList() {

        listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();

        listCountry.add("india");
        listCountry.add("Brazil");
        listCountry.add("Canada");
        listCountry.add("China");
        listCountry.add("France");
        listCountry.add("Germany");
        listCountry.add("Iran");
        listCountry.add("Italy");
        listCountry.add("Japan");
        listCountry.add("Korea");
        listCountry.add("Mexico");
        listCountry.add("Netherlands");
        listCountry.add("Portugal");
        listCountry.add("Russia");
        listCountry.add("Saudi Arabia");
        listCountry.add("Spain");
        listCountry.add("Turkey");
        listCountry.add("United Kingdom");

        listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_1);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_2);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_3);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_4);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_5);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_6);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_7);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_8);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_9);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_10);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_11);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_12);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_13);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_14);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_15);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_16);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_17);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.sample_thumb_18);

    }

}
```

**image_adp:**

```
package com.mkyong.android.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mkyong.android.R;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
    private ArrayList<String> listCountry;

    public ImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listCountry,
            ArrayList<Integer> listFlag) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listCountry = listCountry;
        this.listFlag = listFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;
        public TextView txt;
        public Button btn1, btn2;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            view.txt = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            view.btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            view.btn2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            convertView.setTag(view);
        } else {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));
        view.imgViewFlag.setTag(listFlag.get(position),
                "" + listFlag.get(position));
        // view.txt.setText(listCountry.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**grid_item.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/like" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dislike" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I try out to found thing but not get success in that. how to achieve this .

Thanks for visit my query

Comment: Max Usanin answer is correct, you would set the `OnCLickListener` for your views in the `getView` method of the adapter after the `if-else` clause.

Comment: Luksprog  i write that myClickListener at the end in adapter class and use after if else condition. but still its not working.

Answer (score 2):

in you getView for example

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listenerCheckBox);
```

and listener

```
OnCheckedChangeListener listenerCheckBox = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

        }
    };
```

and you item_grid for example

```
    public class Item {

        private String title;
        private String description;
        private Date pubDate;
        private String link;

        public Item(String title, String description, Date pubDate, String link) {
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.pubDate = pubDate;
            this.link = link;
        }

public String getTitle() {

return this.title;
}
public String setTitle(String title_) {

this.title  = title_;
}

    }
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

if you case

```
 if (convertView == null) {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            view.txt = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            view.btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            view.btn2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);



view.btn1.setOnClicListener(myClickListener);

            convertView.setTag(view);



        } else
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
private OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    };
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Comment: i do it but nothing is working. same as it is. only read only type.

Comment: where button   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" why ?   <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"

Comment: i do not understand, please explain what you mean?

Comment: when i click on item that just click for whole item. i want to do some task on image click and as well as same for button. that button is like yes or no

Comment: i am work on project and i used custom ListView... item listView include text, checkBox... in listView i set android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" in my activity i use urlListView.setItemsCanFocus(true); and all.. then I used the code that wrote earlier

Comment: if i write this click listener or not its not effect my code. i write click event in gird item then its work. but that keep position of previous one .see this http://pastie.org/5546030#6