# Grid item not clickable

Tags: android, gridview

> I have used one gridview calendar in my application.The gridview calendar is working correctly and displayed the element what i want.My problem is when i click the grid item this will not be clickable.Thanks
>
> My Gridview:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayoutid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="-1px"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:textDirection="anyRtl" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> My Grid Rows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gridcal"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/griddate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
    <!-- android:layout_height="200dp" -->
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gridstatus"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

> My Activity:

```
gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridviewid);
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
           //some codes
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you check your gridview id in your activity?

Comment: yes check it out its correct manner.

Comment: Put Log.d(); and Check what is print `position` variable

Comment: not enter inside onclick

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13910008/1318946 check it

Comment: This is a longshot but try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your grid row root (the LinearLayout)

Comment: May you have to check click event of innerView instead of gridView

Comment: @ken wolf its not working

Comment: @Pratik Butani I am not understand what you are telling please give brief

Comment: check above link @Satheesh you have to do like that way

Comment: @Satheesh - Where are you setting the `onClickListener` in the code ? Can't you just put `android:onClick="onClickCustomFunction"` in each of the `TextViews` and create a public function called `public void onClickCustomFunction(View v)` and in it have a `switch (v.getId()) ``case R.id.griddate:` and `case R.id.griddate:` ?

Comment: Set the children of the GridViewItem clickable=false perhaps the onClickEvent is fired on them.